# I have a general question about using TRPC inside react to handle forms

Tags: reactjs, typescript, trpc

**The user flow i would like:**
User clicks on existing "card" to then go to a single card view showing all the data inside. The user can then click edit which will then show them a form of inputs filled in with the previous pages data. These input can be edited by the user and then "saved" by submitting the form, redirected, and seen on the single card page again. data was updated.

**Technologies:** I am currently using a prisma ORM, zod for type checking, trpc, typescript, and react.

**Issue/question**: What is the best way to handle getting data from trpc/db, adding data to the form for it to be editted (a controlled form), and then submitted that form to an updating function with trpc. I am all good with getting the data from trpc/db and showing it to the user. I am having an issue with grabbing data from trpc on the edit page and then handing it off to useState to handle all the changes to the elements.

Is using useState for form changes not the right move? am i missing something in trpc for this type of editing data?

I can show the code but at this point i think i just need high level ideas about the flow of data and form usage OR pointed to the right documentation (as i've looked and have come up with bupkis).

**Current Direction:**

Currently I am Making the trpc call in the component, then a useEffect that is watching trpc data to change, and then using the useState set func to take the data from trpc and playing it in the useState variable. I am then controlling the form with this useState data which when form is submitted is getting place into the trpc update func.

functions in question. Currently this seems wrong as i lose the shape of the object with the initialization of the useState as an empty object literal.

````
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});

const { data, isLoading } = api.dashboardRouter.getOnePacket.useQuery({
    id: card_id_from_URI as string,
  });

useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      setFormData(data);
    }
  }, [data]);```
````

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.